# Save & Close doc and excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word, outlook

**Outline:**

I am not too sure how to go about this, but I need to save documents (word and excel) in a created location using VBScript.

**Background:**

Our servers host my company's PST files. Each week the server restarts and has backups that run. Due to some people not closing their outlook each Friday, the backup's don't always succeed. We have a script that currently closes outlook on computers now, however have noticed another issue where attachments like excel and word cause issues with the original vbs not closing outlook.

**Requirement:**

I would like to close all doc and excel files and save them to a temp location on each user's desktop.  To allow the rest of the script to run.  The reason I say all is that they may have some other doc's and excel files open that are not a part of the attachments.

**Code:**

I currently do not have any working code as I don't have any expertise in VBS.
The code I do have is per below:

```
Sub OpenManual()
    Dim objWord

    'We need to continue through errors since if Word isn't
    'open the GetObject line will give an error
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    'We've tried to get Word but if it's nothing then it isn't open
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
         'No need to do anything
    Else
        'It's good practice to reset error warnings
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Open your document and ensure its visible and activate after openning
        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.Activate
        objWord.SaveAs("C:\Temp\SavedDocuments\")
        objWord.close
    End If

    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What isn't working about the code you have? Do you get errors?

Comment: You really should post TWO questions for this: one for Word, one for Excel. They need different code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Problem is it's not even doing anything it doesn't run doesn't show errors.  I'm currently testing on an open attachment from outlook not sure if that's the issue though

Answer (score 0):

Well, if Word isn't open then nothing at all will happen. Assuming you mean Word is open when you run the code then objWord.SaveAs isn't valid - you can't save the Word.Application, only documents open in the application. That should be giving an error. Same for objWord.Close: the Close method is only available for Document objects, not the application. The application needs to be .Quit

You need to loop the Documents collection and save each one, specifically.

```
Sub OpenManual()
  Dim objWord, doc

  'We need to continue through errors since if Word isn't
  'open the GetObject line will give an error
  On Error Resume Next
  Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

  'We've tried to get Word but if it's nothing then it isn't open
  If objWord Is Nothing Then
     'No need to do anything
  Else
    'It's good practice to reset error warnings
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Open your document and ensure its visible and activate after openning
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Activate
    For Each doc in objWord.Documents
      doc.SaveAs("C:\Temp\SavedDocuments\" & doc.Name)
      doc.Close
    Next
    Set doc = Nothing
    objWord.quit
  End If

  Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You're correct, the document and application are open. I'm trying to save documents which will then be force closed using taskkill via a batch.  If I can't save as how can I save the document to a designed location?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer.  The code executes, but nothing occurs. Whether it is an attachment word or just a normal one, it doesn't save it to C:\Temp\SavedDocuments

Comment: So, if you run the code sample I provided in STEP mode (press F8 so that execution goes line-by-line)... Does each line execute and are all open documents "hit", or does the code suddenly stop (and where)? What kind of logging is available in your environment - you should check what doc.Name is providing (assuming the code gets that far).